# clean html a string by element id using php

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

as you can see by the subject am looking for a tool for cleaning up a HTML string in php using a HTML id property, example:

According to the following PHP string I wish to clean the HTML erasing the **black11**

```
$test = ' 
<div id="block1">
    <div id="block11">Hello1 <span>more html here...</span></div>
    <div id="block12">Hello2 <span>more html here...</span></div>
</div>
<div id="block2"></div>
';
```

Will became

```
$test = ' 
<div id="block1">
    <div id="block12">Hello2 <span>more html here...</span></div>
</div>
<div id="block2"></div>
';
```

I already tried the tool from htmlpurifier.org and can't get the desirable result. Only thing I achieved was removing elements by tag; erasing id; erasing class.

Is there any simple way to achieve this using purifier or other?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

As a general solution for manipulating HTML data, I would recommend :

- Loading it to a DOM document : [**`DOMDocument::loadHTML`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)
- Manipulating the DOM

  - For example, here, you'll probably use [**`DOMDocument::getElementById`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)
  - and [**`DOMNode::removeChild`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php)
- Get the new HTML string, with [**`DOMDocument::saveHTML`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)

Note : it'll add some tags arround your HTML, as `DOMDocument::saveHTML` generates the HTML that corresponds to a full HTML Document :-(

A couple of `str_replace` to remove those might be OK, I suppose... It's not the hardest part of the work, and should work fine.